# when i trying to install npm install gulp -D these errors displaying

Tags: laravel

```
node verison:13.5.o
npm verison:6.13.4
C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\Vertical>npm install gulp -D
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\Vertical\node_modules\.staging\popper.js-2aaaefdd\dist\umd\popper-utils.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\Vertical\node_modules\.staging\bower-e9eb3ed8\lib\node_modules\filled-array\readme.md'
npm WARN The package popper.js is included as both a dev and production dependency.

npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/object-assign/-/object-assign-4.1.1.tgz failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
```

Comment: You seem to have lots of trouble using `npm`, looking at your other questions. have you considered reinstalling `node`/`npm` on your machine? Is "Vertical" a package you're using or a vanilla Laravel installation?

Comment: actually i am working as a trainee in company.i was trying to set up a admin panel by using documention. i will run cmds according to documentation.but i got many errors